# Adding www. To Devise Emails Or Rails In General?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

So I am using Devise and in my Forgot Password emails; it contains this:

```
<%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token) %>
```

The problem I am having is that the `edit_password_url` is making the link appear in emails without a 'www'. I use a 301 redirect in my application_controller so when users click on the link in their emails; it will redirect to the homepage instead.

My question is: Is there any way to make `edit_password_url` include the www. in the URL? I've used the `:protocol => "https"` before but not sure if that would work with this somehow?

Thanks,
James F.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `:subdomain => 'www'` to your edit_password_url hash of options

```
<%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token, :subdomain => 'www') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `:host` as an option to the `edit_password_url` helper.

Also check out the section **Generating URLs** on the [ActionMailer::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) documentation for setting `default_url_options`.